# Checking if PHP script by cronjob is still running

Tags: php, cron

I'm running a script that transfers data from a remote server to local database using cronjob at 8am, and another script 5 minutes later to check whether the data loading has completed or not.

```
0 8 * * * /usr/bin/wget http://myboringsite.com/loaddata.php
5 8 * * * /usr/bin/wget http://myboringsite.com/checkloaddatastop.php
```

How can I check whether loaddata.php has stopped running using a php script (checkloaddatastop.php)?

Comment: You can use ps with something like: ps aux | grep checkloaddatastop.php | grep -v grep

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ps` command like this:

```
ps aux | grep checkloaddatastop.php | grep -v grep
```